# How do you link to a specific version of a shared library in GCC

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, debian

I'm compiling some code which uses libcurl on a Debian Linux system. My dev machine is running Debian 5 but I want the binary to be usable on older Debian 4 systems too.

I find that if I specify **-lcurl** it will link to libcurl.so.4 but Debian 4 systems only have libcurl.so.3

Is there some way I can tell GCC to link to either libcurl.so.3 (which exists in both Debian 4 and 5) or just libcurl.so so it will use whatever version is available ?

Comment: On the older Debian, isn't libcurl.so a symlink to libcurl.so.3 ? I mean, it looks strange that -lcurl does not the right thing by default.

Comment: kastauyra: the versions are not, or at least cannot be assumed to be, binary compatible. So when you link it records the major version linked against in the binary: if you compile on the newer system it will require version 4 and not work on the old system.

(Actually what it records is the soname, which is a string stored in the library file which conventionally but not necessarily is something "libcurl.so.3")

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass the specific version shared library file using the syntax `-l:libfoo.so.1` that specifies the filename instead of the syntax `-lfoo` that specifies the library name following the convention `libfoo.so` on the linker command line, and it ought to do what you want as can be seen at the [linker documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) section for the option `--library=namespec`.

> If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename

In order to provide more details on how to link to a specific version through an example, consider a system that contains two versions of the same library, namely `libfoo.so.1.0` and `libfoo.so.2.0` installed in one of the library directories, in this case `/lib`.

```
$ ls -l /lib/libfoo*

lrwxrwxrwx root root /lib/libfoo.so     -> /lib/libfoo.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx root root /lib/libfoo.so.1   -> /lib/libfoo.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.1.1
lrwxrwxrwx root root /lib/libfoo.so.2   -> /lib/libfoo.so.2.2
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.2.2

# ldconfig -p | grep libfoo
libfoo.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libfoo.so.2
libfoo.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libfoo.so.1
libfoo.so (libc6,x86-64)   => /lib/libfoo.so
```

A program compiled with the option `-lfoo` will make the linker look for a file that relies on the [naming convention](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/developer_guide/creating-libraries-gcc#creating-libraries-gcc_understanding-library-naming-conventions) and thus resolve to `/lib/libfoo.so` (for a shared library object) or `/lib/libfoo.a` (for a static library object).

> A special file name convention is used for libraries: A library known as foo is expected to exist as the file libfoo.so or libfoo.a.

In contrast to that, a program compiled with the option `-l:libfoo.so.1` will be linked against `/lib/libfoo.so.1`, that is a itself currently a symbolic link to `libfoo.so.1.1` as can be seen from the listing above, a minor update from 1.0.

And finally, a program compiled with the option `-l:libfoo.so.2`  will be linked against `/lib/libfoo.so.2`, that is itself currently a symbolic link to `libfoo.so.2.2` as can be seen from the listing above, a minor update from 2.0 and 2.1.

Should you install a newer version of such library, as long as it is a minor update, there should be no need to recompile programs linked to it, since compatible versions should have the same [soname](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/developer_guide/creating-libraries-gcc#creating-libraries-gcc_understanding-soname) and the symbolic links should be updated accordingly.

> The actual library foo version X.Y exists as the file libfoo.so.x.y. Inside the library file, a soname is recorded with the value libfoo.so.x to signal the compatibility.

```
$ ls -l /lib/libfoo.so.2*

lrwxrwxrwx root root /lib/libfoo.so.2   -> /lib/libfoo.so.2.3
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x root root /lib/libfoo.so.2.3
```

Comment: Ah, that almost works except that libcurl.so is just a symlink to lubcurl.so.4 on Debian and so it still links to libcurl.so.4.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted answer although it is not exactly right for libcurl on Debian 5. What I ended up doing is getting a copy of libcurl.so.3 from a Debian 4 system and linking directly to that by specifying the .so filename as bdonlan suggested.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason. I do `gcc -L. test.c -l:libavs.so.0.2.0`, but ldd shows reference to `libavs.so.0`. Can I tell it to link to exact filename?

Answer (score 95):

Instead of using `-lcurl` use `-l:libcurl.so.3`
And of course also use `-L _installed_path_`

Comment: same problem when it's symlinked. -l:libX.so links to libX.so.Y instead

Comment: This doesn't work for me even with the rpath. ldd shows it linking with one thing. The linked output shows the correct filename. But strace confirms it is loading file.2 instead of file.2.3 and it isn't a symlink.

Comment: it does not really work for me for some reason, even if I replace symlink with actual file and delete all the other libraries its still linking against specific version, which it probably gets from the SONAME

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a symlink local to your project that links to .3, then you can just use -L at compile time. I'm not sure if you'd get a name conflict though, but you could always call it libcurl-old.so just in case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do that will be to use the `--filter` and `--auxiliary` flags of the linker.

They are not very documented, but should allow you to load symbols from different versions of the same library according to the machine you are installed on.