# GCC: Specifying a Minimum Shared Library Version

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

**Background**

I inherited and maintain a Linux shared library that is very closely coupled with specific hardware; let's call it `libfoo.so.0.0.0`.  This library has been around for some time and "just worked".  This library has now become a dependency for several higher-layer applications.

Now, unfortunately, new hardware designs have forced me to create symbols with wider types, thereby resulting in `libfoo.so.0.1.0`.  There have been only additions; no deletions or other API changes.  The original, narrow versions of the updated symbols still exist in their original form.

Additionally, I have an application (say, `myapp`) that depends on `libfoo`.  It was originally written to support the `0.0.0` version of the library but has now been reworked to support the new `0.1.0` APIs.

For backwards compatibility reasons, I would like to be able to build `myapp` for either the old or new library via a compile flag.  The kernel that a given build of `myapp` will be loaded on will always have exactly one version of the library, known at compile time.

**The Question**

It is very likely that `libfoo` will be updated again in the future.

1. When building `myapp`, is it possible to specify a *minimum* version of `libfoo` to link against based on a build flag?
2. I know it is possible to specify the library name directly on the build CLI.  Will this cause `myapp` to require *exactly* that version or will later versions of the lib with the same major revision still be able to link against it (ex. `libfoo.so.0.2.0`)?  I am really hoping to not have to update every dependent app's build each time a new minor version is released.
3. Is there a more intelligent way of accomplishing this in an application-agnostic way?

**References**

[How do you link to a specific version of a shared library in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc?lq=1)

Comment: If you've already made some symbols only available on higher versions of the library then you shouldn't have to worry about the exact library version; applications will only work on versions of the library that contain all the symbols they use.

Comment: For point 2, I think you want to give your lib a soname (libfoo.so.0 looks good).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing *external* library versioning, where the app is built against `libfoo.so.0`, `libfoo.so.1`, etc. Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter5-5.html).

Using external library versioning requires that *exactly* the same version of `libfoo.so.x` be present at runtime.

This is generally *not* the right technique on Linux, which, through the magic of [symbol versioning](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SymbolVersioning), allows a single `libfoo.so.Y` to provide multiple incompatible definitions of the same symbol, and thus allows a single library serve both the old and the new applications simultaneously.

In addition, if you are simply always adding new symbols, and are not modifying existing symbols in incompatible way, then there is *no reason* to increment the external version. Keep `libfoo.so` at version `0`, provide a `int foo_version_X_Y;` global variable in it (as well as all previous versions: `foo_version_1_0`, `foo_version_1_1`, etc.), and have an application binary read the variable that it requres. If an application requires a new symbol `foo_version_1_2` and is run with an old library that only provides `foo_version_1_1`, then the application will fail to start with an obvious error.