# Specifying order in gcc and g++ include and lib paths

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have multiple versions of a library, all with the same name (boost libraries), each installed in its own directory. I know how to instruct the compiler and linker to search in certain directories for header files and libraries (`-I` and `-L`). [I am also aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc) of how to pass the actual library file to the linker.

My question is how to specify precedence in the search path of the compiler and the linker, such that it searches folder `A` before searching folder `B` and takes `A`'s version of the library instead of `B`'s . I'm interested in order between all eligible directories, i.e. the default `gcc` and `g++` ones, and the ones specified after `-I` and `-L`.

My distro is Ubuntu `14.04`, and I use `g++` `4.8` up to `6`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GCC will search your `-I` directories in the left-to-right order in which they
appear in your commandline and it will search all your `-I` directories before
the default `#include` directories. Here is [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options).

GCC invokes the system linker, [`ld`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld), to perform
linkage. Occurrences of GCC's `-L` option, and its `-l` option, are passed through
to the linker with their order preserved.

The linker will search your `-L` directories in the left-to-right order in which
they appear in the commandline and it will search all your `-L` directories
before the default linkage directories. All of the `-L` options, in the order specified,
apply to all of the `-l` options, regardless of how `-L` and `-l` options are intermixed
in the commandline. E.g.

```
-La -lfoo -Lb -lbar
```

is equivalent to any of:

```
-La -Lb -lfoo -lbar
-lfoo -La -Lb -lbar
-lfoo -lbar -La -Lb
```

Here is [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Options.html#Options)

Comment: Hm... But it's still unclear whether it will _stop_ searching once it hits the required include file, or it will exhaust the search. In other words, does the first or the last win. It's not automatically obvious...