# How to force -lssl to link with libssl.so.1.1 not libssl.so?

Tags: ssl, cmake, openssl, linker, shared-libraries

```
root@760501de936d:/home/project/build# ldconfig -p | grep ssl
        libssl.so.1.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
        libssl.so.1.0.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
        libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```

My project is trying to link with OpenSSL. How can I force it to use `libssl.so.1.1`?

I'm using cmake

`find_library(LIB_SSL ssl)`

then

```
target_link_libraries(h264_decoder_cli PRIVATE 
${LIB_SSL} ${LIB_CRYPTO} ...)
```

however I get things like

```
tls_openssl.c:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
```

I don't know why but only the version 1.1 has this symbol

```
root@760501de936d:/home/project/build# nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so | grep OPENSSL_init_ssl
root@760501de936d:/home/project/build# nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 | grep OPENSSL_init_ssl
0000000000033ff0 T OPENSSL_init_ssl
```

I checked how cmake is compiling and it's simply putting `-lssl -lcrypto`

Comment: @xhienne `libssl.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so` what this means? And if it were, then their `nm` outputs woudl be the same

Comment: Check the question on how to [link against a specific version of a shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc)

Comment: @PakUula I tried forcing this behaviour with `find_library(LIB_SSL ssl NAMES libssl.so.1.1 PATHS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)` but I see on the output that it does only `-lssl`

Answer (score 0):

To find OpenSSL CMake has a finder module, so you don't need to use anything else (i.e., `find_library`). Use `find_package(OpenSSL 1.1 ...)` to require particular version.